# USPTO classification databse

Tags: uspto, classification, cpc

I´m new in research in patent classificacions and need to get the CCL: Current US Classification, CPC: Current CPC Classification, CPCL:Current CPC Classification Class and ICL: International Classification. of various patent numbers i used to get them from see the forest, but found out that they had a lot of errors, furthermore I can´t find the bulk database for that information, the anwers that i looked up in this page are good but the links no longer work. Can anyone give me a way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you please explain “I used to get them from see the forest”?

Comment: It is a patent analytic site with an odd name  http://www.see-the-forest.com/G4/Main.act

Comment: You posted a follow up question as an answer. That isn’t how this site works. New questions need to be posted as questions.

Answer (score 1):

[The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/) provides classification codes as fields. You can download the results of a search to various formats including CSV and JSON files. I just tested it and got the following column headers related to classifications:

```
CPC Classifications,IPCR Classifications,US Classifications
```

There is also an [API](https://www.lens.org/lens/user/subscriptions#patents) for bulk queries although that, I believe is not free.

Comment: The OP will not have sufficient rep points to see your comment suggesting re-posting as a new question since it is a comment to a answer that is hidden from the OP.